# Why elastic search does not work in AWS Appsync

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have defined a model in my AWS Amplify like this:

```
type Report 
@model 
@searchable
{
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  location: String!
}
```

While I can create items and also list them, however, I cannot get the items using search query:

[image]

Look at above figure, `searchReports` returns nothing, while I have many reports with title `T` as it can be seen in the result of `listReports`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic search only works on new data. So I needed to truncate the table and refill it again.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: real world ... DB content has some [commercial] value ... go to some/one of your customers and tell him to delete [yearly collected] data ... because sth doesn't work

Comment: I was speaking about development system. In the real world you can feed the elastic search engine. Or you can copy data in a shadow table and read data again.

Comment: existing app upgrade? there should be a possibility to run some reindexing/re-feeding [after some structural changes] ... copy doesn't sound good, too